# Android SQLiteHelper can't create FOREIGN KEY

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm having some trouble with SQLite on Android. I try to create my tables that way:

Trade Shows:

```
String CREATE_TRADE_SHOW_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE tradeShows ( " +
                "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "location TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "doDate DATE NOT NULL, " +
                "createdDate DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "lastModDate DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "pictureUrl TEXT, " +
                "picture BLOB )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TRADE_SHOW_TABLE);
```

It's working fine, and then, Vendors:

```
String CREATE_TRADE_SHOW_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE vendors ( " +
                "id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "tradeShowId INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                "name TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "createdDate DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "lastModDate DATETIME NOT NULL, " +
                "pictureUrl TEXT, " +
                "picture BLOB," +
                "FOREIGN KEY(tradeShowId) REFERENCES tradeShows(id)" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TRADE_SHOW_TABLE);
```

So now my Table Vendors is created, but the tradeShowId FOREIGN KEY is not there. I dont get any error, my table is created just fine, but without the tradeShowId.

What can I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: If you just added the column and the whole column is missing, uninstall the app so the database gets recreated. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more. If the column is there but the foreign key is not enforced, see Michal's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite supports foreign keys, but not by default.

If you write for API level 16 or higher, you should do it in onConfigure method of the SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

In the previous API levels it should be done this way:

```
@Override 
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"); 
}
```

You can read about this in [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> "Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards
>   compatibility), so [they] must be enabled separately for each database
>   connection. (Note, however, that future releases of SQLite might
>   change so that foreign key constraints [are] enabled by default.
>   Careful developers will not make any assumptions about whether or not
>   foreign keys are enabled by default but will instead enable or disable
>   them as necessary.)"